# illegal string offset '@id' in test.php

Tags: php

Not sure if data issue or program issue, sometimes below program 
show error message :

PHP Warning : "illegal string offset '@id' in test.php"
PHP Warning : "illegal string offset 'Order' in test.php"...

```
....
$ret1=curlDest($transaction_url);
$retval = $ret1["Response"]["TransactionList"]["@TotalCount"];
foreach ($ret1["Response"]["TransactionList"]["Transaction"] as $v)
  { 
     $transaction_id       = $v["@Id"];        
     $order_id             = array();
     $orderid_query_string = '';
     foreach ($v["Order"] as $order)
          {...
          }
```

the data of @ret1 is below

```
Array
<
    [@Id] => 120852760
    [Order] = > Array
      <
        [@Id] => YM152222
      >
>
```

Comment: foreach() { if(isset($v["@Id"])) } ....

Comment: why your array contain `<`???   it should contain `{`

Answer (score 0):

The error said

```
illegal string offset '@id'
```

You should use a capitalized `@Id` instead.